# NameNotFoundException injecting EJB in JAX-RS Resouce

Tags: jax-rs, ejb-3.0, jersey-2.0

I've been trying to inject an EJB into a JAX-RS resource *via* `InitialContext()lookup()` getting the following exception:

```
    <javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up 
comp/env/AServiceLocal
in /app/webapp/wcc/1377099157.; remaining name 'comp/env/AServiceLocal'>
```

My lookup in resource constructor:

```
try {

    initialContext = new InitialContext();          
    String jndiSubcontext = "java:comp/env/";

    aService = (AServiceLocal) initialContext.lookup(jndiSubcontext+AServiceLocal.class.getSimpleName());
    eSService = (ESServiceLocal) initialContext.lookup(jndiSubcontext+ESServiceLocal.class.getSimpleName());
    eService = (EServiceLocal) initialContext.lookup(jndiSubcontext+EServiceLocal.class.getSimpleName());

} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the file structure taking into account that they are all maven projects:

```
global
|
--shared
  |
  |---src/main/java/com/x/y/z/AServiceLocal.java (ejb)
|
--war-project
  |
  |--src/main/java/comm/x/y/z/TheResource.java (jax-rs)
```

There are more maven projects related and they are all maven-configured through the global project in a hierarchical way.

There is also a **resource** in the same project as `war-project` that also performs lookups to the `shared` project and they **do** work.

I don't understand what the problem is.

## edit

After adding `ejb-local-ref` to deployment  descriptor:

```
<ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>AServiceLocal</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>com.x.y.service.AdminXProfileServiceLocal</local>
    <ejb-link>shared.jar#AdminXProfileService</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

I get the following error:

> [J2EE:160101]Error: The ejb-link "shared.jar#AService"
>   declared in the ejb-ref or ejb-local-ref "AServiceLocal"
>   in the application module "xyz-99.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" could not be
>   resolved. The target EJB for the ejb-ref could not be found. Ensure
>   that the link is correct.

The jar `shared.jar` is a dependency of the war project, but it seems that location is not correct. Must I add the packages also to the `ejb-link` ?

Something like: `<ejb-link>shared.jar#com.x.y.ServiceImpl</ejb-link>`

I aslo need to point out that there is a mix of hk2,cdi and lookups as part of the injection due to the fact the project is quite old and also it was migrated to weblogic 12c version recently so normal `@Inject` or `@EJB` don't appear to be working.

Comment: Where are you packaging the shared.jar?  Are you packaging it inside an EAR, or are you relying on EJB-in-WAR (added as of EJB 3.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take into account all the variables I am seeing like Maven, project structure, JNDI lookup etc... the best way is to add an entry in the web.xml of the war project referencing your ejbs.

```
<ejb-local-ref>
   <ejb-ref-name>ejb/adminXProfileService</ejb-ref-name>
   <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
   <local>com.myapp.ejb.AdminXProfileServiceLocal</local>
   <ejb-link>YourEJBLibrary.jar#adminXProfileService</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Then in your lookup you simply look for:

```
contenxt.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/adminXProfileService");
```

Comment: Hi Leonardo, thank you for your response, I added that snippet but now it says that the ejb-link is not right, I've updated the question to include this.

Comment: Try to give a name to the ejb such as `@EJB(name="adminXProfileService")` then reference it exactly in ejb link.